# defining a type for a nonempty list

Tags: haskell, recursion, types

I'm trying to get used to defining recursive types in Haskell. As a simple exercise, I figured that defining a nonempty list data type would be easy (and potentially useful).

Here is my attempt:

```
data NonemptyList a = Singleton a | Cons (Singleton a) (NonemptyList a)
```

which results in the compile error:

> Not in scope: type constructor or class `Singleton'
>   Failed, modules loaded: none.

The following code compiles but doesn't sit well with me. I can't exactly explain why not.

```
data NonemptyList a = Singleton a | Cons  a (NonemptyList a)
```

Can anyone clarify this for me? Any comments are welcome.

Thanks

dan

Comment: In your case, `Singleton` is a *data constructor* — you use these to define values. When defining types, you use *type constructors*. These two are different concepts and you can't mix them. All I can say is that the second option (the one that works) is perfectly fine, I don't know why you don't like it.

Comment: The fields of a constructor are types, not constructors.  Notice how the second field of `Cons` is `NonemptyList a`; `NonemptyList a` is a type.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear replies. I think I understand my mistake now. In the following code, Singleton is a data constructor and SingletonType & NonemptyListType are type constructors.  This code compiles. 


data SingletonType a = Singleton a
data NonemptyListType a = SingletonType a | Cons  (SingletonType a) (NonemptyListType a)

Answer (score 9):

This is because you used `Singleton` (a data constructor) in a place where a type constructor is expected. In this example, `Singleton` and `Cons` are data constructors and `Nonemptylist` is a type constructor. It is easy to confuse these two concepts, because it is common to define a data constructor and a type constructor with the same name, e.g. `data Foo a = Foo a`.

In this case, `data NonemptyList a = Singleton a | Cons  a (NonemptyList a)` probably is the correct code to use.

Answer (score 4):

As a side note, a simpler way to define a non-empty list is:

```
data NonEmpty a = NonEmpty { head :: a, tail :: [a] }
```

The most popular package for non-empty lists is the `semigroups` package, which has something similar to the above definition in the [Data.List.NonEmpty](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/semigroups/0.9.2/doc/html/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) module.

Comment: I see now. This is essentially the same as: inline 'data NonEmpty' a = Nonempty' a [a]` That's as clear and simple as it gets.

Comment: @sitiposit That's right.  I only included the field accessor names just to also get those two functions for free.